# Can't get the jedi-vim plugin to work

Tags: vim, jedi-vim, python-jedi

I'm trying to use the [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) plugin for Python autocompletion but I can't get it to work.

I have Vim 7.3, and here's what I did:

1- clone the code from

```
git clone http://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim path/to/bundles/jedi-vim
```

2- copy `jedi-vim/plugin/jedi.vim` to `~/.vim/plugin/`

3- copy `jedi-vim/doc/jedi-vim.txt` to `~/.vim/doc/`

Now when I open vim, enter the insert mode and type

```
import wave
wave.
```

nothing happens, though the doc specify `Autocompletion is also triggered by typing a period in insert mode`, and if I try `<Ctrl-Space>` I get the following error

```
E29: No inserted text yet
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I checked `:map` and it seems that `<Ctrl-Space>` is not used:

```
n  [m          *@:call <SNR>21_Python_jump('?^\s*\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  [[          *@:call <SNR>21_Python_jump('?^\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  ]m          *@:call <SNR>21_Python_jump('/^\s*\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  ]]          *@:call <SNR>21_Python_jump('/^\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
```

Since I got an error using `<Ctrl-Space>`, I guess it must do something, right? Why can't I see it with `:map`?

What am I missing?

**edit**

:scriptnames

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: ~/.vim/plugin/jedi.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/vim.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/python.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

**edit 2**

I updated Vim to 7.4 and installed `vim-jedi` using `pathogen` as described in the [doc](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim):

1- install jedi
2- install pathogen
3- add `execute pathogen#infect()` in my `~/.vimrc`
4- clone git repository in `~/.vim/bundle/`

I create a new file, and I still have no autocompletion. Eg:

```
import numpy as np
np.
```

and control+space in insert mode returns:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

Is there any `omni completion` plugin conflicting? I haven't installed such plugin...

Should I had anything else to my `~/.vimrc` file?

Comment: I don't understand step 1 and 2. They don't seem to make any sense. Just remove that stuff again. Do you use pathogen, vundle or vam? I don't see the `<Ctrl-Space>` command in `:map` either, but you should see some other Jedi commands (`leader-d` for example). Please also post `:mes` and `:scriptnames`.

Comment: 1 and 2 is to install jedi-vim. I edited my question to add the output of :scriptname.

Comment: As long as there's no `jedi-vim` in your scriptnames, it obviously won't work. But that's not jedi-vim's fault, it's either pathogen/vundle/vam's fault or your mistake. (In your current `scriptnames` I don't see jedi-vim. But maybe it's there after edit 2? I don't know.)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I installed `jedi-vim` with [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), and it now works.

**EDIT**: to reply to the comments below: I get jedi-vim to work by reinstalling it using pathogen instead of installing it from source. This fixed my issue, so I considered it to be an answer.

Comment: An usage example/command might be of help here( consider elaborating your answer ).

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: How come this be an answer ? This is not helping in any way.

Answer (score 18):

This is the basic installation of Jedi with Pathogen.

1. **Install Pathogen**

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
   curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
   ```
2. **Configure`.vimrc`** 
    **if you have a `~/.vimrc` file:** add the following line to it

   ```
   execute pathogen#infect()
   ```

   **else:** create a blank file named `.vimrc` at your home folder and add the following lines to it.

   ```
   execute pathogen#infect()
   syntax on
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```
3. Install Jedi.

   ```
   cd ~/.vim/bundle/ && git clone --recursive https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim.git
   ```
4. ### enjoy!

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I've spent hours trying to make VIM my next IDE. Yours is the only (unambigious) way I got working. I wonder if the pink pop up box you pictured is still expected? I get a 1/4 - 1/3 off the top of the window taken over, but that is for help on a MWE.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! This works best

Answer (score 6):

If you have

```
set paste
```

in your .vimrc file, jedi will fail to run.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error because of a mismatch between the python version I intended to use and the one that was called.

Make sure jedi is using the intended version of python. E.g. add
`let g:jedi#force_py_version = 3` to your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your vim version is too low,I suggest you update to vim 7.4 and make sure it has open the python function,If you want autocomplete function, I suggest you can try [You complete Me](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe),It is more powerful,it need Vim 7.3.584+,now the vim 7.4 is come out,it is easy to install, you can install in this ways,

```
#!/bin/bash  
MyInstallDir="/root/MyVim74Install/"  
cd ~  
mkdir MyVim74Install  
if [ -d $MyInstallDir ]; then  
  echo "create MyInstallDir success"  
else  
  echo "create MyInstallDir Error"  
 fi  
cd $MyInstallDir  
pwd  

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz  
tar -zxvf ncurses-5.9.tar.gz  
cd ncurses-5.9  
./configure  
make  
make install  
make clean  

cd ~  
cd $MyInstallDir  
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.12.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf cmake-2.8.7.tar.gz   
cd cmake-2.8.7 
./bootstrap   
make
make install

wget ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.4.tar.bz2  
tar -jxvf vim-7.4.tar.bz2  
cd vim74 ./configure --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --enable-xim   --enable-fontset \
--with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp=yes --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config
make 
make install
make clean 

git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle 
apt-get install gcc  
apt-get install g++ 
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ctags/ctags-5.6.tar.gz  
tar -zxvf ctags-5.6.tar.gz  
cd ctags-5.6  
./configure &&make &&make install  
ctags -R
```

Comment: 1. You don't need VIM 7.4 to use jedi-vim. Jedi-vim works perfectly fine with 7.3 (and even some lower versions, but some things like call signatures are ignored [no `+conceal`].
2. YouCompleteMe is not more "powerful" than jedi-vim for Python. It uses the exact same engine (`Jedi`) . It does support more languages, though.